# SQL Query with Multiple Joins and exclusions

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables Table A=Orders and Table B=OrderDetails where they are joined by the unique order_no.

For each ORDER_no in the Order TableA there can be multiple rows attached to it in OrderDetails TAble B.  Basically i need a query to exclude the entire Order in both tables if any of the rows in TAble B equal a specific name.

Example:

If the Order 1234 has 5 rows in the OrderDetails TableB and one of those rows = 'NOTE' then I want the entire ORder 1234 excluded from results.  Currently its only excluded that row but showing the other rows ?

Comment: Stick to same names, i.e. either Orders and OrderDetails, or TableA and TableB. Current mix is too confusing.

Comment: add some sample code

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?  It gets the orders that don't have a "notes" detail record:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from orderdetails od
                  where od.orderid = o.orderid and od.name = 'Notes'
                 );
```

If you want all the detail records, you can join in `orderdetails` in the outer query.

Comment: Yes that seemed to work, now i just have to adjust for additional joins to other tables. Hopefully i can add the complicated joins now that i'm only selecting those orders with NO NOTES.  Thank you.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you for the quick response and deciphering my question, i'm new to this :)